# Проблемы с перемещением изображения

Tags: html

HTML:

```
<img id="waves" src="img/waves.png">
```

CSS:

```
#waves { 
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Мне надо переместить картинку на центр страницы, но ничего не происходит. 
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе тут мешает `float: left;`

Но если хочешь чтобы было по центру можешь убрать `float:left;` и добавить `text-align: center;` как показано внизу, но при этом этот стиль задать блоку в котором будет содержаться твоя фотография.

***CSS***

```
#waves { 
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="waves">
<img src="img/waves.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Совсем не нужно оборачивать картинку в контейнер, достаточно добавить ей `display:block`: https://jsfiddle.net/ep3nmb56/

```css
#waves {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<img id="waves" src="http://www.familyfriendpoems.com/images/hero/nature-nature.jpg">
```